# save image from image path

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans, jfilechooser

I implemented this code for browsing an image using `JFileChooser` but problem is I cannot implement code for saving image on local disk.
OR 
If possible I directly want to display this image in a new `JFrame` class and this is going to be a dynamic link

```
private void btnBrowseVideo1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    mediaUrl = null;
    String path = "";

    path = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
    path = path.trim();

    // System.out.println("URI : "+mediaUrl);
    if (path.endsWith(".jpg") || path.endsWith(".JPG")) {

        lblBrowseImage.setText(path);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "SELECT .jpg  FILE!!!!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope my interpretation of the question is correct. Look at [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) `read()` and `write()` methods for loading and saving images. Also, see [Working with Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) and [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) tutorials for more details and examples.

Here is an example that displays the image selected by user in a standard dialog for simplicity:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class ShowImage {
    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Load Image");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton loadButton = new JButton("Display Image");
        loadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(
                        System.getProperty("user.home"));
            fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                    "Image files", new String[] { "png", "jpg", "jpeg",
                            "gif" }));
                if (fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    try {
                        Image image = ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile());
                        if (image != null) {
                            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
                            panel.add(new JLabel(fc.getSelectedFile().toString()), 
                                    BorderLayout.NORTH);
                            panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,  panel);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        frame.add(loadButton);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } 
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: see i have a gui that selects an image on a button action and i have posted that code
now i have also created a new jframe.class with 2 jlabels 
on button click this new jframe.class is loaded
jlabel1 shows an image having a fixed path
i want jlabel2 to display the image which has been selected by my above code

Comment: @Akshay I'm not sure what is question. You can use `setIcon` to set icon on `JLabel`, ie: `jlabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));`. You can see the last edit that pops up a panel with two labels.